# Click Javascript button with C# webbrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I need to make a program click a javascript button for me in the webbrowser. Is this possible in any way? I want to accomplish this in C#

the button

```
INPUT id=str class=text style="TEXT-ALIGN: center" maxLength=4 size=3     value=558 INPUT onclick=doIt_new(1); id=strBtn type=button value=doIt
```

Yes its the default webbrowser object in visual studio

Comment: Is the web browser a default IE browser?

Comment: Just to confirm - you are using WebBrowser control on a WinForm?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WinForm WebBrowser control - take a look at [webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method. It allows to execute JavaScript inside of a document, hosted in WebBroswer control.

Answer (score 0):

```
string html =
  @"<html>
    <script>
        function doIt_new(x){
            alert(x);
        }
    </script>
    </html>";

webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("doIt_new", new object[] { 1 });
};
```